# Why this SQL query with DATE not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `reservation`
(
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    `from` DATE,
    `to` DATE
);

INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ('aaa', '2013-04-23', '2013-05-06');
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ('bbb', '2013-04-01', '2013-08-06');
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ('ccc', '2013-05-12', '2013-05-19');
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ('ddd', '2013-06-01', '2013-07-27');
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ('eee', '2013-06-23', '2013-07-06');
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ('fff', '2013-07-23', '2013-08-09');

SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE 'from' <= '2013-07-01' AND 'to' >= '2013-07-01'
```

LIVE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80d9cd/2

I would like get all records with period in 2013-07. This query should return me:

```
2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
4  | ddd    |  2013-06-01  |  2013-07-27
5  | eee    |  2013-06-23  |  2013-07-06
6  | fff    |  2013-07-23  |  2013-08-09
```

because period 2013-07 is > to and < from in this records. Why this return me 0 records? How can i get these records with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the working one

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80d9cd/5

you have `from` and `to` are reserved mysql keyword you should around it by backticks

Answer (score 4):

Your column names should not be in quotes. They should be in ticks:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservation 
WHERE `from` <= '2013-06-01' 
AND `to` >= '2013-06-01'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80d9cd/3